# How to create address book?

Tags: polkadot-js

I'm making a **wallet** that has an **address book / contacts** feature so that it's easier and faster for users to send balances to other users.

Is storing the **address book / contacts** in the **network** is a good and correct way?

Should data such as contacts not be stored in blocks but stored in local storage?

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion there is no need to store the list of contacts of a user on chain, I can't see the benefits and it costs fees.

Storing in the local storage might be enough (with an option of export/import even better)

PolkadotJS UI has this functionality: [Address Account](https://support.polkadot.network/support/solutions/articles/65000170036-polkadot-js-ui-the-difference-between-accounts-and-address-book), and it uses the [keyring](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/ui-keyring/start/addresses/) ([@polkadot/ui-keyring](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polkadot/ui-keyring)) to store them.

If you want to store it on chain anyway, Polkadot for example has the [identiy_pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/identity/README.md) that allows a user to register its identity on-chain. It makes easier among other things to identify people and send them balances.
You can think of building something similar (pallet or smart contracts) to store the list of contacts of a user.